# LXC and Saltstack minion_id configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lxc, saltstack

I'm using LXC as a lab platform for testing SaltStack scripts. The lab consists of +5 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS containers, which I create by cloning a template container with `salt-minion` pre-installed.

Once I create the template container and install `salt-minion`, the template gets its Salt `minion_id` based on `hostname` (`test-template`). If I `lxc-clone` this template, all clones will have that template's `minion_id`, but I would like clones to have `minion_id` matching their `hostname` (`test-machine-{1,2,3,4,5}`).

Is there a way to make this scripted with `bash` or should I take another path to the same effect?

**UPDATE**:

I looked into some of `lxc` scripts and found out that `lxc` scripts use `/usr/share/lxc/lxc.functions` file which defines `get_default_lxcpath` function, so my current script looks something like this:

```
. /usr/share/lxc/lxc.functions

# clone template
lxc-clone -o $template -n "$container"

# create saltstack minion config dir if does not exist    
minion_id_path="$(get_default_lxcpath)/$container/rootfs/etc/salt"
mkdir -p "$minion_id_path"

# set minion-id directly from container name
echo "$container" > "$minion_id_path/minion_id"
```

I don't like this solution since it depends heavily on internals of both lxc and saltstack, but does the job.

**UPDATE 2**:

After suggestion in comments about how `salt-minion` will generate new `minion_id` when existing one is deleted, I reduced this to two commands:

```
. /usr/share/lxc/lxc.functions

# clone template
lxc-clone -o $template -n "$container"

# delete minion_id to allow salt-minion to generate a new one
rm "$(get_default_lxcpath)/$container/rootfs/etc/salt/minion_id"
```

I'd still like to see more generic/robust approach not depending on SaltStack and LXC internals.

Comment: If you delete the minion_id from the template then it should be automatically re-created on the next start up of the salt-name and will take the clone vm's hostname by default. I am not familiar with lxc but does the hostname get set before or after the salt-minion startup?

Comment: `/etc/hostname` is created in the same run when `lxc` is created. But, that's great hint, because I can replace last two commands with `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`docker`](https://www.docker.io) with a [`dockerfile`](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/builder/#id2). You can easily find examples online for both [`salt-minion`](https://github.com/kstaken/dockerfile-examples/tree/master/salt-minion) and [`salt-master`](https://github.com/kstaken/dockerfile-examples/tree/master/salt-master).

Grab the files and proceed to build the images (it's always a [good idea to tag them](http://crosbymichael.com/dockerfile-best-practices.html)). Given a directory structure like this one (closely following the examples pointed above):

```
docker/
├── salt-master
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── supervisor-salt.conf
└── salt-minion
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── supervisor-salt.conf
```

you need to `cd docker/salt-master` and issue:

```
# docker build -t kstaken/ubuntu-salt-master .
```

the equivalent for the `salt-minion`:

```
# cd docker/salt-minion
# docker build -t kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion .
```

This process creates reusable images:

```
# docker images | grep kstaken
kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion   latest              557c052f5b14        19 seconds ago      253.5 MB
kstaken/ubuntu-salt-master   latest              1f41866d05e1        5 minutes ago       262.7 MB
```

that you can start in the foreground (and attach to them) or in the background, as needed. You can also [link](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/#linking-a-container) them:

```
# docker run --detach=true --hostname=salt-master --networking=true kstaken/ubuntu-salt-maste
# docker run --detach=true --hostname=minion1 --networking=true --link bersek_morse:linked-server kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion
# docker run --detach=true --hostname=minion2 --networking=true --link berserk_morse:linked-server kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion
```

The result is very easily scriptable:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4fae47241a73        kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion:latest   /usr/bin/supervisord   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                             goofy_fermi
6030e7f882ba        kstaken/ubuntu-salt-minion:latest   /usr/bin/supervisord   25 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                            desperate_hawking
22b18a387e21        kstaken/ubuntu-salt-master:latest   /usr/bin/supervisord   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        4505/tcp, 4506/tcp   berserk_morse,desperate_hawking/linked-server,goofy_fermi/linked-server
```